# Не получается создать сводную таблицу с нужными параметрами через VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Мне нужно создать сводную таблицу куда будет помещаться статистика об уникальных значения со всех листов в книге в дополнительный новосозданный лист. Допустим есть такие значения как Театр, Кино, Парк, Работа, Игральная площадка и тд. Эти слова встречаются по несколько раз в разных листах. Нужна сводная таблица где можно было бы подсчитать количество театров, парков и т.д а также подсчитать общее количество всех этих слов. Но при этом таблица изменяется (не мной). Необходимо чтобы если количество парков было 0, то это ячейка всё равно отображалась в сводной таблице и при подсчёте выдавало 0. Подскажите как это можно осуществить?

Comment: Это можно осуществить макросом. Универсальных кодов нет: каждая конкретная задача имеет свои особености; таблицы с различным расположением данных; разные требования к обработке и оформлению данных.

Comment: Можете какой нибудь пример предоставить? Я попробую изменить под свои нужды.

Comment: Да ну? Пример и описание Вы должны предоставлять. Да и такая задача - она больше для фриланс-площадок.